# discrepancy in double to Float class conversion in java

Tags: java, casting, floating-point, type-conversion

I am trying the below code but after executing `344741.79` value is showing as `344741.78`

Means after decimal place `.79` is getting converted to `.78`, I am really wondering why I am not getting the exactly same value after conversion and which logic is doing this?

```
public static void main(String[] s) {
    double a = 344741.79;
    System.out.print(new Float(a));
}
```

Comment: You lose some precision when converting from a `double` to a `float` in Java.

Comment: And while that may or may not be the case here, you also lose precision during compilation when converting from that Java source code literal to `double` (which cannot represent all decimal fractions either).

Comment: You should use the BigDecimal class if you require precision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Float` is only guaranteed to accurately store [6 significant decimal digits](http://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-digits-required-for-round-trip-conversions/). In the case of 344741.79, the 2 nearest `Float`s are 344741.78125 (which is printed as `344741.78`) and 344741.8125 (which is printed as `344741.8`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time :)

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, please accept it by clicking the tick.